# Transfer javascript variable to external page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, variables

I need to retrieve an attribute from an image. This attribute then needs to be send to the original page. I use a .load to load the page where you click on an image, which then retrieves the attribute, on the "internal" page.

So what I basically want:

1. You get on the "internal page"
2. You click on an image from the ajax-loaded "external page".
3. The attribute "src" is then loaded into a variable
4. This variable gets send back to the "internal page"
5. I can use the sent variable.

This is what I got so far:

External page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".imgid").click(function() {
        var imgname = $(this).attr('src');
        var xhr;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // all browsers
            else xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  // for IE

            var url = 'internalpage.php?js_var=' + imgname;
            xhr.open('GET', url, false);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState===4 && xhr.status===200) {
                    var div = document.getElementById('update');
                    div.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                }
            }
            xhr.send();
            // ajax stop        
    });
});
</script>
<fieldset>
    <label for="portal_id">Afbeelding Portal</label>
    <?php $photos = Beeldbank::find_all(); ?>
    <?php $rows=3; $cols=4;$i=1; $row_counter=0; echo '<table>'; foreach($photos as $photo): if($row_counter<$rows){
    if($i==1) { echo '<tr>'; }
    echo '<td>'.'<img src="../'.$photo->image_path().'" width="125" class="imgid" />'.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.'<input type="hidden" id="filename" name="filename" value="'.$photo->naam.'" />'.'</td>';
    if(($i%$cols)==0){ echo '</tr><tr>';  $row_counter++; }
    }
    $i++; 
    endforeach;
    echo '</table>'; ?>
  </fieldset>
```

Internal page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascripts/SelectImage.js"></script>
    Afbeelding Portal<br />
    <button id="select_portal" type="button">Selecteer Afbeelding</button>
    <div id="dialog-form" style="display:none; position:absolute; width:auto; height:auto;"></div>
```

The js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#select_portal" )
      .button()
      .click(function() {
                $("#dialog-form").css("display", "block");
                $("#dialog-form").css("top", "50%");
                $("#dialog-form").css("left", "50%");
                $("#dialog-form").css("backgroundColor","white");
        $("#dialog-form").load("externalpage.php");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right you need to post the result back to a php page. So you can use [jQuery POST](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) to send a value you have read using jQuery.

Comment: Well all I really need is to get a variable (the imagename). I have read something about javascript session calls. Is that something I could use here?